# BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null for displayid = 0 is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

After going through:

[Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087983/unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-valid-is-your-activity-running)

[Android 'Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application' exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933206/android-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-exception)

[Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

[BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running? in activity.isFinishing statment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675828/badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-valid-is-your-acti)

[Problems creating a Popup Window in Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187673/problems-creating-a-popup-window-in-android-activity)

[It returns null when I use getView() to get root View of the Fragment in the ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437839/it-returns-null-when-i-use-getview-to-get-root-view-of-the-fragment-in-the-vie?rq=1)

I'm not entirely sure if having a null View element as root causes this exception. I have a DialogFragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acquire_fragment, container, false);

    mErrorTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.error_textview);
    mRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mLoadingView = root.findViewById(R.id.screen_wait);

    Toolbar toolbar = root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
            mListener.onFinishActivity();
        }
    });
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.button_purchase);
    return root;
}
```

Can **root** be null when .findViewById()  is called?

Comment: I think it's the `container` that is null, could it be that the activity associated with this dialog was at the time this dialog was being created?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir It happens on some devices; is it possible to postpone onCreate() until all parameters are initialized?